# Windows Search does not work in "Libraries/Documents"

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

The Windows Search (top right) does not work in `Libraries/Documents`

When I try to search something (i.e. "flowers") there is just nothing happening. In other folders the search works.
I use Windows 7 Professional 64bit.

[image: example of nothing happening when searching]

Comment: Does this same issue exist if you perform a search on Computer? And what happens after you type your search and hit return you leave it for 5 minutes? Does it catch up with itself?

Answer (score 0):

In the registry, go to:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Curre ntVersion\Explorer\Advanced

and change that value of "Start_SearchFiles" from 0 to 1

Restart the indexing service

If any files are not showing then (and this is a quote from another site): 
*As for the txt files, I had to "touch" them all before search would
find them. Strange, but all is working now.*

[Source](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t731301-windows-7-search-not-working.html)